# How to deal with references to shared manager classes

Tags: c#, architecture

I am using C# with MonoGame, although this is relevant for any object-oriented programming language

Static classes should be reserved for stateless utility classes (for example System.Math) and they should generally be avoided along with singletons for manager-like classes. The reason for this is it prevents object-oriented strategies and may be under the false pretense that there is only one instance required at all times.

To solve these issues you could have instances like AudioManager, EffectManager, Time, etc. in a single global static object. But this does not solve another issue which is you do not control who has access to these instances. So instead pass in these instances from the top down through constructors to classes who need to access certain things.

In my game I have an entity component system. Character derives from Actor which derives from Component which is contained within an Entity. When a Character gets hit I want time to stop briefly (Time instance), the camera should shake (Camera instance), he should flash white (Effects instance), Damage text should be spawned (FloatingText instance) and a sound effect should be emitted (AudioManager instance).

This is just one example and child classes may need more things or pass in different parameters to these instances. Additionally, anyone higher up the hierarchy will need more instance references if they need to pass it down to someone who is lower down.

Q: "What is the problem in that?" A: "It is cumbersome and I am modifying an entire hierarchy when I want to change something one place"

If I realize a component needs a reference to another instance I need to modify the code throughout the entire hierarchy. A solution is to make the global static object itself a non-static instance and pass down the whole thing to all components (but I might only pass down a certain instance to other parts of the game).

"Maybe you just have a coupling problem? Character should not be the one to stop time, shake camera, etc."

Okay, who should then? I could use an OnHit event in Character and let AudioManager for example hook up to that for all characters and play a sound effect with different parameters depending on the type of Character. But now I need to make a switch statement on type inside AudioManager, not very object-oriented. Instead, I could have one request manager instance to all of these things that takes in a parameter list as well. But what is the difference between this and a shared object instance? Anyone with a reference to request manager can make any request it's just a bit more indirect.

Passing in a container to all shared instances in the constructor of e.g. Component seems like the best compromise. What do you think?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for a dependency injection framework — they're designed to help make plumbing these references to the places they're needed more manageable, while keeping the strict avoidance of mutable global state you seem to want.

Comment: Complete overkill. It uses reflection and you will get many runtime errors rather than compiler errors. Requires a bunch of boilerplate code of my (say, 50 different component classes) that I would have to go back and modify constantly. Using the Service Locator pattern seems more appropriate. I think I will stick to a static class that contains instances of services/managers I want to be globally available. Globals are bad when you directly change the internal state of an object from various places. The services I put there could be thread safe and made to serve different clients.

Comment: For example, the AudioManager might play or schedule a sound effect and add it to a list
so all sound effects can be paused. An enemy will not be able to manipulate a
sound effect played by say the player.

The data they have access to and manipulate is separated.

Making read-only data available globally can be OK as well I think.